# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: python, django, ajax, api

I am trying to connect django and Vue API to login.
I am using JWT with simple jwt and djoser library, and I have already created user.

As you can see the postman, it works fine.
Does anyone know how to fix this error??

[image]

However, I cannot connect from index.html (ajax)

This is the ajax.

```html
....
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    email: '',
                    password: ''
                },
                mounted: function() {},
                methods: {
                    login(){
                        if (this.email == ''||this.password == '') {
                            alert("Email or password cannot be empty");
                            location. reload();
                        } 
                        var data_l = {};
                        data_l.email = this.email;
                        data_l.password = this.password;
                        var formData = JSON.stringify(data_l);
                        console.log(formData);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/",
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: formData,
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function(rs) {
                                console.log(rs);
                                if (rs.code == "0") {
                                    console.log(rs);
                                    alert("Login successful!");
                                    window.location.href = "";
                                } else {
                                    alert(rs.msg);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function() {}
                        });
                    },
                    jump_to_signup() {
                        window.location.href = "signup.html";
                    },
                    jump_to_Fpwd(){
                        window.location.href = "forgotpassword.html";
                    }
                }
                    
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',

    'fitness_app',
    'user',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fitness.urls'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: you have to enable CORS for the app running at localhost:8000 https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some lines in your middleware list. Replace it like this in your `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Also, I think that you are using the old attribute by using `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL`. Use this instead:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

If you have any questions ask, and remember, the documentation is right here: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers